# Run a command with sudo without changing server privileges

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to execute a command from PHP using roots privileges. I can't change the server privileges so I have to do it by passing the password directly.
I've seen it's possible to do it by reading a file with the password, so I want to create a tmp file with the password and delete it when the command is done.

```
    $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PASSWORD'); 
    $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
    fwrite($handle, "passwordhere");
    fclose($handle);
    echo exec('sudo -u root -S whoami < '.$tmpfname);
    unlink($tmpfname);
```

It should return 'root' but it doesn't. What's wrong in my code?

EDIT: Maybe some extra security from Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution regarding security, is to enable only the needed commands in sudoers file to be used by www-data without password.

You can see an example here: http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-php-sudo-befehle-mit-php-absetzen?pid=37843#pid37843

***other solution that works with storing your password in the php script, see below this line.***

except from the security risk at all.
you do not need to store the password in a file.

Just do this:

```
➜  tmp  echo 'your_root_password' | sudo -S whoami
Password:root
```

Also works perfect with php

```
<?
echo exec("echo 'your_root_password' | sudo -S whoami");
```

Returns:

```
➜  tmp  php sudo.php
root%
```

Best regard,
André

Comment: For some reason, the command works correctly when I execute it from a terminal but it doesn't returns anything when it's called from PHP.
BTW I'm using Codeigniter so maybe there is some kind of extra security in the framework.

Comment: i found another solution that maybe works better.
[link](http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-php-sudo-befehle-mit-php-absetzen?pid=37843#pid37843)
it is in german. if you need any help, just let me know.

in conclusion.
you have to enable the www-data user to exactly run your disired shell command without using a password.

Comment: That's a good solution. Please, add it to your answer and I will mark it as accepted. If the exec works for you, maybe you can leave it there as well. Thank you.

Comment: added it to my answer as the best practice solution.